# Private cloud setup Error- Fileserver not started

Tags: anylogic

I am setting up anylogic private cloud, when ran the install script, it fail to start fileserver docker.
exception - java.io.IOException: com.jcraft,jsch,JSCHException: Algorithm negotiation fail
Any pointers?

looked into trouble shooting guide
https://anylogic.help/cloud/troubleshooting.html#rsa-sha

Comment: if you use the private cloud, you'd want to check with AL support directly :)